# C++ Waiting for Multiple Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I can't seem to find an exact answer to the threading question I have. I currently have a program that polls the Kinect V2 sensor for new frame data using OpenNI2. The problem is I need to poll each type of sensor; depth, IR, and RGB separately in order to get them at the same time. Here is where my threading questions comes in, I want to poll each of the three sensors in their own individual thread and when all functions calls have returned continue with the data processing.

I understand how to link each new thread to the main thread to ensure all threads finish before the program exits, but how do I wait in the middle of my program for a specific set of threads to finish? Is there a function or feature of std::thread in c++11 that I am overlooking or is this something that needs to be manually done using a mutex or semaphores?

pseudocode:

```
std::thread thread_RGB(Kinect::readFrame(Enum::RGB), kinect_1);
std::thread thread_IR(Kinect::readFrame(Enum::IR), kinect_1);
std::thread thread_depth(Kinect::readFrame(Enum::depth), kinect_1);

// Wait for all threads to finish getting new frame data
...

// Process data here
process_data(kinect_1.RGB_data);
process_data(kinect_1.IR_data);
process_data(kinect_1.depth_data);
```

Comment: Call `join()` for all threads consequently.

Comment: Right but, once the threads are joined how do I tell if they have all finished execution? Doesn't join just ensure that the main thread wont exit until every thread has completed. The part I am unsure how to implement is the waiting for them to finish in the middle of the code.

Comment: `thread_RGB.join(); thread_IR.join(); thread_depth.join(); ` or store the threads in a container and call join() in a loop on the container.

Comment: The `join` function *waits* for the thread to finish. Once the `join` function returns the thread is truly finished, its "main" function has returned, and the `std::thread` object can be safely destructed. Please see e.g. [this `std::thread` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) for more information.

Comment: ahh okay, then that was a misunderstanding on my part with how join() worked. So if I join all of the threads the next block of code wont execute until the threads that were joined previously finish?

Comment: @Wired365: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses that was a lot easier than I expected. @Someprogrammerdude if you want to make your comment an answer I can accept it or I can write it up myself.

Comment: `join()` will work. However it's common in high performance situations (and this sounds real-timey) to implement worker threads (probably one for RGB, IR and depth that either respond to requests to read or read on some polling frequency to deliver (relatively) up to date data on demand.
In the on-request circumstances you implement a condition_variable that monitors 3 flags unset for "go" and set back for "ready" or acts as a semaphore (set a flag to 0 and wait for it to reach 3). Creating and destroying threads can have a burdensome overhead.

Comment: @Persixty thanks, that's a good suggestion. As of right now the thread creation and destruction aren't my bottlenecks when it comes to performance, it's all of the image processing, but I'll keep that in mind for future threading.

Comment: @Wired365 In your question it says you're 'waiting' for the sensors then continuing with the data processing. So the DP might be the lions share of the time but that would say you're in series. That is (simplistically) an iteration takes DP+SENS where SENS is the slowest sensor. If you want SENS back write the polling version that estimates DP and maybe even adapts to deliver a result just-in-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.join` method to wait for the threads to finish and then destruct them. When you call `t.join()` there is a check if the thread is still doing something and if the work is done the thread is joined. If the thread is not joinable(there is also `t.joinable()`) the main thread will wait till the secondary thread finish its work and then join it.

In your case you can add these lines.

```
thread_RGB.join();
thread_IR.join();
thread_depth.join();
```

Here is an image I found on google that shows how `thread::join()` works.

[image]